# Is there a way to prevent a PR from being merged until after Jenkins build complete

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins

Is there a way to prevent a Pull Request from being merged in GIT until after a Jenkins build was completed? The Jenkins build URL is posted in a comment for that PR.

Comment: There is no such thing as "GIT enterprise". There is only one version of Git. Please refine your question.

Comment: I think they may mean "Github Enterprise". After all, there is no formal concept of a pull request in "Git" per-se.

Comment: As mentioned, Git != GitHub. Are you using [this plugin](//wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin), and do you have it set up to update the [Commit Status](//github.com/blog/1227-commit-status-api)? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Stash/Bitbucket, you can use "Post receive" hook on Stash: Stash Webhook to Jenkins, which will trigger Jenkins job. Then configure Stash/Bitbucket in Pull request section: Requires a minimum of successful builds.

After Jenkins job will be successfully performed, you will be able to merge PR.